# FB Graph API: how to get all entities, using pagination

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all posts I'm liked on Facebook, using Graph API (without SDK). I'm able to get first page of data, and can't understand how to fetch  next data page using cursors.

My request looks like:

```
GET /v3.2/me/likes?limit=100
```

And response is something like this  :

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "<name>",
      "id": "<id>",
      "created_time": "2018-12-08T08:48:47+0000"
    },
    ...
    ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTQ5MTkzOTE2NDQ2OTQyNAZDZD",
      "after": "Mjk5NzQzMTYzNTI1Mjc3"
    }
  }
}
```

Adding "after" parameter to request, causes empty response:

```
 GET /v3.2/me/likes?limit=100&after=Mjk5NzQzMTYzNTI1Mjc3
```

Will be glad for help.

Comment: /me/likes is not _posts_ you liked, but _pages_. There is no API to get every post you liked.

Comment: @misorude Thanks for quick answer . So  only available option is manual crawling of likes  using DOM/HTML parsing ?

Comment: Would be, but that is not actually allowed. And Facebook has measures in place against server-side scraping. Your best bet is probably to use some client-side scripting to extract this info from the “Likes and Reactions” in your Activity Log.